# Is it possible to prevent "copy and paste similar template special case" for this code?

Tags: c++, templates

I have some program which reads vector recursively like this:

```
#define ARRAYTOJSON(x) arrayToJson<decltype(x)>(#x,x)
template<class V>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c,V& v){
    typedef typename V::value_type E;
    for(typename std::vector<E>::iterator it=v.begin();it!=v.end();++it){
        arrayToJson(c,*it);
    }
}

template<>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c,int& v){
    printf("%s %d\n",c,v);
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(5);
    ARRAYTOJSON(v);

    int i=0;
    ARRAYTOJSON(i);
    return 0;
}
```

but now I want to add special cases for 2 new class with a test() method:

```
class A{
public:
    void test(){}
};

class B{
public:
    void test(){}
};
```

what I need to do now is to copy the special case and place it in code:

```
template<>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c,A& v){
    v.test();
}

template<>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c,B& v){
    v.test();
}
```

is there any syntax that force the special case (if no other special case can be used) to use generic template special case like:

```
template<>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c,B& v){
    v.test();
}
```

so that I no need to copy and place each special case for each class?

Comment: Why not try to add a base class for all your special cases ?

Comment: Do you want a version of `arrayToJson` enabled when `V` has a member function called `test`?

Answer (score 0):

You could write two unspecialized versions which are tag-dispatched on whether or not `V` has a member function called `test`:

```
//you'll need void_t for this
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct has_test : std::false_type{};
template <typename T>
struct has_test<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().test())>> : std::true_type{};

//base case
template <typename V>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c, V& v) {
    //tag dispatch
    arrayToJsonImpl(c,v,has_test<V>{});   
}

//int specialization
template <>
inline void arrayToJson(const char* c,int& v){
    printf("%s %d\n",c,v);
}

//V does not have test
template<class V>
inline void arrayToJsonImpl(const char* c,V& v,std::false_type){
    typedef typename V::value_type E;
    for(typename std::vector<E>::iterator it=v.begin();it!=v.end();++it){
        arrayToJson(c,*it);
    }
}

//V does have test
template <typename V>
void arrayToJsonImpl(const char* c,V& v, std::true_type)
{
    (void)c;
    v.test();        
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4684850566bebc8)